# Start execution from indexAction() in IndexController in ZEND Framework

Tags: zend-framework

In indexAction() method of IndexController I have called the method of model which returns the list of employees(employeeList) from database.And then add this this employeeList to $view and then call $view->render('index.phtml') and index .phtml shows the employeeList.The code is ad follows:

IndexController.php

```
<?php

require_once('../Zend/Controller/Action.php');
require_once('../models/HRModel.php');
require_once('../Zend/View.php');

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
 protected $hrModel;

     public function init()
     {
            $this->hrModel = new Application_Model_HRModel();

     }

     public function indexAction()
     {
           $view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' =>'../views'));
           $view->employeeList = $this->hrModel->queryAllEmployees();
           echo $view->render('index.phtml');

     }


 }
```

Application_model_HRModel.php

```
<?php
require_once('Zend/Db.php');
require_once('Zend/Config/Ini.php');
class Application_Model_HRModel
{
   protected $db=null;

   public function queryAllEmployees() {

   return $this->db->fetchAssoc("select comment from guestbook");

}
```

}

index.phtml

```
foreach ($this->employeeList as $emp):
extract($emp);

echo '$EMPLOYEE_ID';

echo $comment;

endforeach
```

Now I want to start the execution from indexAction() method.But how to do this?What should be the url to be entered in browser?In request parameter the controller will be IndexController and action will be indexAction.So Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: where you set the document root ZF?

Comment: In my project,in application folder there are 4 folders named as configs, controllers,models,views.In library folder I have included Zend folder containing all classes of Zend framework.Since I have to start from Index controller So i set web root as application/controllers and in run configuration set project url as http://localhost:8888/Index/index where controller is Index and action is index.When i run this in browser it says as"Warning: require_once(../Zend/Controller/Action.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream:

Comment: You must set document root the directory public and go page: `localhost:8888`, but i suggest you the read this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have set now as application/public.But still same problem occurs.I have set document root in apache httpd too And I have read that manual given by you and applied all things but......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute this action, you need to call the Index Controller with index Action. So you use www.foo.bar/index/index or simple www.foo.bar.
If this dont work, you have maybe a error in your confoguration.

Or did i mistake your question?

How did you configure your PHP Error handling? Maybe you have a PHP error that is not displayed.

Comment: When i request the url localhost:8888/Index/index in browser it says Warning: require_once(../Zend/Controller/Action.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 2 And I have included all Zend classes in library folder(as I am using netbeans).

Comment: Since I have to start from Index controller So i set web root as application/controllers and in run configuration set project url as localhost:8888/Index/index where controller is Index and action is index.What else has to be done?The main thing is that I have to start execution from index controller and from that controller onwards I apply $view->render('index.phtml').So thing is that start execution from indexcontroller's indexAction() method.Thanks for reply.

Comment: Why dont you use the autoload function of Zend to include all required files?